# FIrefox: how to save ajax-generated source?

Tags: firefox

I have web page that loads some of it's html via jquery's load method. Using Firefox's Developer toolbar (Inspector tab),  I can view the rendered source. But I **can not select or save** the rendered source.

Viewing the source via **Right-Click > View Source** does not show me the content loaded via ajax.

Here's my load method:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var url = "http://example.com/ad_content.html";
$('#target').load(url, "",

);
```

});

Answer (score 4):

Press `ctrl+a`, then right click and choose: "View Selection Source". You will see the ajax-generated source.

Comment: This simple solution was exactly what I was looking for. A website had tons of javascript that rendered the majority of the page, making it very difficult to 'see' the HTML elements, CSS and other things. Using this tip, I can view the entire rendered HTML, inline CSS and inline Javascript. Thank you!